# Unit test file utility class with delete directory method

Tags: java, file, unit-testing

I have a file utility class with the deleteDir function

```
@Override
public boolean deleteDir(File file) {
    File[] contents = file.listFiles();
    if (contents != null) {
        for (File f : contents) {
            if (! Files.isSymbolicLink(f.toPath())) {
                deleteDir(f);
            }
        }
    }
    file.delete();
    return true;
}
```

I have another class with a method that calls this deleteDir function of the file utility

```
@Override
    public void zipFolder(List<String> listOfFiles, File file, ZipOutputStream zos) {
        try {
            int index = 0;
            for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                if (this.fileValidator.isHiddenFile(f))
                    continue;
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    File returnedZipFile = zipFileInFolder(f);
                    File fileToBeRemoved = writeIntoZip(returnedZipFile, index, zos);
                    this.fileUtility.deleteDir(fileToBeRemoved);
                    index++;
                } else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    List<String> listOfFilesInDirectory = this.directoryProcessor.getAllFilesInDirectory(f);
                    String fullZipFullName = this.pathNameUtility.getFullFileName(f.getName(), FileConstants.ZIP);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fullZipFullName);
                    ZipOutputStream zosInner = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
                    zipFolder(listOfFilesInDirectory, f, zosInner);
                }
            }
            zos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have read that we should not mock a File. I want to unit test the 2 methods. How can i do so? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not a `Mock`, is a `Spy`, [spy](https://www.bazipFoldereldung.com/mockito-spy) is like a selective mock when you can have some methods that call real operations and others can be mock. So when testing `zipFolder` you can mock your `deleteDir` call.

Answer (score 0):

Both your functions are dominated by interactions: Interactions with other components, interactions with the file system.  Interaction dominated code should rather be tested with integration testing.

For example, in your `deleteDir` function, you could certainly try to mock all calls and then test the code.  But, how would you mock the call to `file.delete()` at the end of the function?  Probably you would write the mock to simply do nothing but return true.

Unfortunately, this will not help you find one of the bugs in your code: You do not delete symbolic links.  But, this will then also hinder your code to delete the surrounding directory, because to be deleted a directory must be empty.

Unit-testing and mocks will not help you to find this problem, but integration testing (that is, running the code together with a file system and directories with different contents including symbolic links) will show you that it does not work.